# What the purpose of close "my own" question instead of just deleting it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges

I've unlocked the [View close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege recently, but I don't clearly understand it.

> This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions.

- Viewing votes is understandable, maybe I can check the close/reopen vote to adjust my content.
- Reopen is understandable, I can explain or edit my question to reopen it.
- But why closing? If I knew(before others) my own question need improved or off-topic, I could just edit it or delete it?

I've already know when to cast a "close vote" to other's post, but I wonder **why self-closing instead of self-deleting?** Is there any **benefit to the community**, or any **specific purpose** lead me choose to "self-closing" instead of "self-deleting" or "editing"?

Comment: You can vote on your own question as a dupe, if you find out later that it exists already. You can also close a question as not reproducible if the error goes away without knowing how or why. These would be valid reasons. If the question already has some traction, then leaving it visible might be more beneficial than removing it altogether. The question might be relevant in the future. I don't see why you want these actions restricted. Surely it makes *less* sense for question authors to have *less* tools available on their own posts than on others'.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the comment, I'm not saying I wan't to restrict these action, I just can't  find out when and why to use it (but I get it now).

Comment: Your question can be answered and if it’s a duplicate and/or the problem cannot be resolved, that would mean the question should be closed.  Deleting a question with an answer is toxic behavior.

Comment: But if gave an answer and someone finds a dupe and you concur with it, then you can also vote to close it, but get scolded for that

Comment: @nbk not sure I understand - who is scolding who?

Comment: @VLAZ Moderators and high rep users do that

Comment: You have almost 30k points, @nbk. Fairly high-rep. That means you spend your time scolding low reputation users? Maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: @yivi i scould as senior member people if the have problem in their question images for example, but not if a answer was given, that solves the problem. I also don't downvote dupe answers

Comment: @nbk - Why are you not looking for duplicates before you submit your answer to such a question?  Certainly, if the question is later closed, a duplicate could be found, which means whoever is answering didn't bother looking.

Comment: @SecurityHound as i mentioned countless tomes before, you can't get a gold badge without answering dupes, because no one will upvote answers

Comment: @nbk - You act like I know what you have said in the past? I certainly was able to earn a gold badge in a tag simply by submitting answers to questions.

Comment: Gold badges are for the weak. I have a gold badge. I am weak. QED.